# How to invoke Locust tests programmatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, locust

Tried this with Locust up on my localhost (127.0.0.1:8089), but it gives 400 bad request error:

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8089/swarm', params={"locust_count":10, "hatch_rate":5})
print response.text
```

Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

I had verified that http://127.0.0.1:8089/ is indeed up by browsing it from the browser. The code for `locustfile.py` is available at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378215/how-to-make-a-post-request-with-headers-and-json-payload-in-python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start locust from your code then you have 3 options :

1. (Not the preferred one but working )You can run Locust using the CLI (--no-web, -c , -r )
   https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/running-locust-without-web-ui.html
2. Implementing the locust loading logic on your own :
   https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/222 (Using the code provided in the message thread)
3. Using Invokust:
   https://github.com/FutureSharks/invokust

The first option, even though not the most "pythonic" is the easiest to do. I am still trying my luck with the 2nd option.

Comment: Thanks Abhimanyu for your response. I'll try option #1 to start with.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution the simplest:

```
import os
from locust.main import main


def run_locust(**kwargs):
    os.environ['LOCUST_HOST'] = kwargs.get('LOCUST_HOST')
    os.environ['LOCUST_RUN_TIME'] = kwargs.get('LOCUST_RUN_TIME', '1m')
    os.environ['LOCUST_NO_WEB'] = str(kwargs.get('LOCUST_NO_WEB', True))
    os.environ['LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE'] = kwargs.get('LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE')
    os.environ['LOCUST_CLIENTS'] = str(kwargs.get('LOCUST_CLIENTS'))
    os.environ['LOCUST_HATCH_RATE'] = str(kwargs.get('LOCUST_HATCH_RATE'))
    main()
```

According to the Locust documentation configuration parameters might also be passed as environment variables. Consequently, we can use them as I show in example above.

Firstly, we set needed environment variables using `os.environ[<variable_name>]` and secondly, we run the main function of locust `main()`.

Documentation: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#all-available-configuration-options

Comment: please try to explain the answer, it will help the community for future references

Comment: please more explanation

Comment: @blkpingu thank you for pushing :) It's done now. Hope it'll help.

Comment: The main method is full of sys.exit calls. Use this only if you don't care about that. IMO, the method should've used appropriate exception handling.